# Memcpy with a void pointer

Tags: c, memcpy

I am having trouble with the `memcpy` function. I need a function that stores data into a `void` pointer. Here is a simple example of it:

```
void saveData(void* data)
{
  char inputData[] = "some data";
  memcpy((char*)data, inputData, sizeof(inputData));
}
```

However I get segmentation errors when I do this, even though it compiles just fine. My function argument has to be a `void` pointer because I may have different data formats to input and I may not know the size of the data ahead of time. Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Please and thank you.

***UPDATE:
Thanks all for the helpful responses. As most of you pointed out, I did not initialize `void* data`. That fixed it.
Now my question is: when I do dynamic allocation for the `void* data` (or even `char* data`), I give it a size, but when I do `memcpy`, it allows me to write  an ever bigger string than I first assigned space for. I also tried just doing `char* data`, and the same thing happens. This is my sample code:

```
char inputData[] = "123456789";
void* data1 = malloc(5*sizeof(char));
char* data2 = (char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char));

memcpy(data1,inputData,sizeof(inputData));
memcpy(data2,inputData,sizeof(inputData));
```

When I print out the results, the entire string of `inputData` get copied even though I only allocated enough space for 5 chars. Shouldn't that give me an error?

Comment: Show the caller, that's where the problem is. It's passing you a pointer you can't write through.

Comment: Did you `malloc()` enough memory for `data` to store "some data"?

Comment: a segmentation error, in this context, means `data` is probably less than the size of your text data. By the looks of it, it should be at least 10 bytes

Comment: Strings literals like "some data" are not placed in writable memory. Since inputData points to this, writing to it will fail.  You need to give it the address of a static array or else use malloc().

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: To your second question: C does not check the length of your buffers when it copies - it's one of the ways that it speeds things up for you.  You are responsible for making sure all your memory allocations are large enough.

Comment: Not sure what the `5` is for. Moreover `sizeof(inputData)` does work here as `inputData` is an array. But please be clear that were you instead to try to store a `char* inputData = "value"`, you'd get the wrong length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function parameter `data` needs to point to somewhere that there is memory available.
You could do something like this:

```
int main()
{
  char myString[256];
  saveData((void*)myString);
}
```

If you prefer to use `malloc` and `free`, then your code would be more like this:

```
int main()
{
  char* myString = (char*)malloc(256);
  saveData((void*)myString);
  free(myString);
}
```

..the trouble with both of these is that you don't know how long the string needs to be. It would be far safer/easier to use std::string.

```
std::string myString;  // an empty string
myString += "some data"; // append a string
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `C` so I'm assuming `std::string` is out of scope. But the rest of this answer looks great.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the size of the source is not given by `sizeof` but by strlen. Assuming the caller does not want to allocate memory, you need to `malloc` storage and have the void* store a handle to that. Given the save function calls malloc, I'd set up a corresponding release function.

```
bool saveData(void** retSave, const char* input)
{
    bool success = false;
    size_t storageSize = strlen(input) + 1;
    void* store = malloc(storageSize);
    if (store)
    {
        memcpy(store, input, storageSize);
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}



void releaseSavedData(void* savedData)
{
    free(savedData);
}

int main()
{
    void* saveHandle = 0;
    bool ok = saveData(&saveHandle, "some data");
    if (ok)
    {
        releaseSavedData(saveHandle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` needs to point to somewhere you have access to write.  The null pointer area you don't have access to (unless you're running DOS or something).

Use `malloc` to allocate a chunk of memory to copy from `inputData` to.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the size of the data ahead of time, the only way to get this to work is to malloc some arbitrarily large buffer and make sure you NEVER copy more than that # of bytes into the void*.  Not the best design, but it will work.

Also, don't forget to allocate an extra byte for the NULL char on the end of the string, and don't forget to actually put the null on the end of the memory buffer.  In the example above, your string in `data` won't have a NULL on the end.